# Python Car Sales Project having a bit of an issue

Tags: python

Hello I'm a college student whose just begun to take a computer programming class and have hit a bit of a snag I'm struggling to figure out.  The program I'm supposed to create using python is a car sales program that calculates the weekly gross pay that is the total of made from the cars sold in the week.  I have to input the number of cars sold and the value given back should be how much was made that week, this is the code I have written :

```
def main():

    car_number = float(input('enter number cars sold'))

    def calculate_total('car_number,price,commission'):
        price = 32,500.00
        commission = .025
        total = car_number * price * commission
        return total

main()
```

on the line `'def calculate_total('car_number, price, commission'):` I am receiving a syntax error declaring `'formal parameter expected'` How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That line should be

```
def calculate_total(car_number,price,commission):
```

You are instead writing a string there.

Also, as you are changing the values of `price` and `commission` it is better defined as

```
def calculate_total(car_number):
```

You have forgotten to call the function at the end

```
return calculate_total(car_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

`def calculate_total('car_number,price,commission'):` this line should be

`def calculate_total(car_number):`